# C++ Return to command input function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a simple program that takes a user command, executes a function, then returns to the original function so the user can enter another command, much like windows command prompt. Upon browsing the similar questions I read that returning to main is not good programming so I want to ask:

How can I make a function that has access to the other functions but the other functions can return to once they finish their process?

Comment: You must have misunderstood, there's nothing wrong with returning to main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a function `return`s, control is returned to the calling function.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int other_function(){
    std::cout << "In other_function...\n";
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << "Calling other_function()...\n";
    int ret_value = other_function();
    std::cout << "Back in main. other_function returned "
               << ret_value << ".\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This little program starts in `main`, calls `other_function` and then returns back to main. It prints, out the messages with `std::cout` as well. Try the program if you don't understand the concept.

Also, I personally see no problem with doing all of this in `main`, perhaps in a `while`-loop. What people mean (generally) when they say you shouldn't always return control to main is that you want to keep all of your functions short, preferably about as large as your screen. However, the `main` function is there for a reason, so use it (with care).

Just make sure that the functions have been declared (or `#include`d), and your function should be able to call them all.

Good luck!

Comment: The key point is to put your "execute command" function in a loop.  And make sure the loop has a definite terminating condition, of course :)  You can - and arguably should - do this in "main()".

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely NO problems in returning to `main()` function.

In your case, you can do an algorithm in a way like this:

- Step 1: Start Main() function
- Step 2: Read the command from the user
- Step 3: Compare the command by using `if()` and `strcmp()` function.
- Step 3.a: Call the function for the command.
- Step 4: Repeat through step 2.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to just use std::string instead. Seeing as how he seems to be a beginner and C-style strings aren't very beginner-friendly. And besides, he's doing C++, not C.

Comment: Yes, he can use Strings of any implementation. But the algorithm remains the same. And, for C++, it's better to use `std::string`.